# WebDeploy not listening on port 8172

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

I'm try to deploy a simple web application from my dev machine to IIS running on a Windows 7 Professional virtual machine.

On this machine I did the following:

1. Installed Web Deploy 3.6, making sure all features get installed.
2. Made sure the Web Management and Web Deployment Agent services are set to Automatic and currently running.
3. Enabled port 8172 in Windows Firewall (no other firewall installed). The rule was already there but not enabled.
4. Temporarily turned off Windows Firewall to make sure it's still not blocking the port.

When I try:

```
netstat -aon | findstr :8172
```

I get no results, so nothing is listening on this port.

As a test, I installed VS 2012 on the server and publishing with Web Deploy works fine. However, this is not the way I need to do it.

What else can I try to make sure that the services are listening on port 8172?

Answer (score 25):

There are two more steps you should check:

## 1. Enable Remote Connections in IIS

Just connect to the remote server through RDP, open IIS and open this option:

[image: IIS Management Server in Features View]

In the right panel, stop it. This will actually stop **Web Management Service**. Then you will be able to check **Enable remote connections** flag. Check it, click the **Apply** option in the right panel, then **Start**.

This is also necessary for enabling you to remotely connect to this IIS server from other computers (like your dev computer).

[image: IIS Screen]

---

## 2. Check Network Security Groups (if using AWS, Azure or some other service)

If you are using AWS EC2 or Azure, opening 8172 port on the virtual machine itself is not enough. There are security groups with inbound/outbound rules as well.

For AWS, you open your EC2 panel, go to **Security Groups**, then add a Custom TCP Rule for port 8172 as an Inbound Rule. Make sure you do it to the right Security Group (the one used by your Virtual Machine).

[image: AWS Screen]

Now, if you are using Azure:

1. Open [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).
2. Select "Virtual Machines" in the left panel.
3. In the table, there is a column "Resource Group". Click the resource group for your VM.
   [image]
4. Click in the Network Security Group.
   [image]
5. Add the Inbound Rule for port 8172.
   [image]

That's it.

Comment: Thank you. That just fixed my problem

Comment: @MOH I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: Well, I m still facing same issue.
I'm using azure virtual machine, I have already open port 8172 both windows firewall and network security group on the virtual machine resource group.  

Is there any suggestions  ?

Comment: @MSK did you enable remote connection on IIS? (step 1)

Comment: Actually first step is completely ok. I m using azure and now I have problem with installing octopus tentacle. It uses 10933 port and I have added windows firewall exception. Also opened security rules for that virtual machine.

Comment: Ok my problem was outbound rule of our company. Neither firewall nor network security group. Tnx!

Comment: Thanks. In my case, remote connections were already enabled but access for unspecified users was denied. Enabling it fixed the issue.

Comment: Yeah mine was that is was working, but for some reason the service had stopped. Was looking in all the wrong place, your answer led me to simply hitting "Start"