# Web deploy fails s the server experienced an issue processing the request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webdeploy

Web deploy has been working fine for me via Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019. Yesterday, it failed. I've made no changes to the server, although Windows Updates are on

```
4>MSDEPLOY(0,0): Error : (04/03/2020 18:45:08) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
4>MSDEPLOY(0,0): Error : The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
4>MSDEPLOY(0,0): Error count: 1.
```

I tried to FTP my site, which connects fine.

I turned off the firewall on my VPS, and the same error message is shown.

The website builds fine locally.

The `.tmp` file shows the following stack

```
04/03/2020 18:09:20
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__213.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
```

I don't know how to debug this further

Comment: try deleting your `obj` and `bin` folders.. doing a clean and rebuilding

Comment: @JamieD77 when you say this, do you mean for every project? Or just the project I publish? Any way, same issue. I don't believe it's a build issue at this stage...

Answer (score 0):

I am clueless as to why but, it seems the fix was simply to accept connections in the firewall on Port 8172

Comment: Because port 8172 is used by Web Deploy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540532/webdeploy-not-listening-on-port-8172

Comment: Thanks @IanKemp. I mean, I made no changes to the firewall on my VPS... At all. So no idea why it is failing today and not yesterday